# Can framer-motion simultaneously animate a 3D rotation and a layout change?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, framer-motion

I'm trying to use Framer Motion v10.6.0 to animate "flipping and dealing a card" at the same time. I'm using a `motion.div` that changes parents with a fixed `layoutId`. It should animate changing parents and rotating in 3D (`rotateY`) at the same time. On their own, these two operations behave as expected, but after a layout change, the 3D rotation is not animated. 2D rotation and translation behave as expected and animate alongside the layout change.

[image: Edit musing-johnson-jyrpf1]

I recreated what I am trying here. When executing `Change Parents + Rotate 2D + Translate`, all animations play correctly - the div spins around 180 degrees and "lands" in its new parent with an offset. `Rotate 3D` on its own also plays correctly and animates a "flip". When executing `Change Parents + Rotate 3D`, I expect to see similar results. Instead, the rotation is applied instantly.

I have also tried using various `initial` props, such as excluding it and matching the `animate` prop.